# Transform complex features into simple features GML with HALE

Tags: geoserver, wfs, xml, gml, geoserver-app-schema

#### Background information:

I'm working with complex GML features and would like to publish my data as a WFS service through GeoServer. I know there is already the application schema support (app-schema) extension which provides support for Complex Features in GeoServer WFS. 

What I have to do now is to create a mapping file. I'm just trying to figure out what the best options are.

I found out that the HALE Alignment Editor ([See here](https://www.wetransform.to/products/halestudio/)) is able to create a mapping file from simple features through the alignment between the source and the target schemas.

I think the program is very useful to create a mapping file on a visual basis using simple features as input. Nevertheless, I found no information if you can transform your data in the opposite way (Complex into Simple).

#### Question:

Is there a way to break down the complex features so that I can import them as simple features into the HALE Alignment Editor?

**Something like this:**
Complex Features -> "Transformation" -> Simple Features -> "HALE Alignment" -> Complex Features + App Schema -> Ready to use with GeoServer

Comment: HALE can do complex features too, for example: https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/complex_features/geosciml/index.html

Comment: You're right, but I think that's a different approach. The example above imports multiple source schemas and harmonizes them to a new target schema. 
In my case: my source schema describes my complex features. The target schema is the same. I thought it might be possible to create a mapping file by a conversion of the complex features and a reverse transformation.

Answer (score 1):

As @nmtoken mentioned before, HALE can work with complex features. 
The thing is, that the plugin in hale studio that do an export to a GeoServer AppSchema mapping only supports a PostGIS source schema.

**To make a long story short:** for my approach it's not possible to use HALE, because my data is stored in a gml file. For more details see the [Plugin documentation](http://help.halestudio.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Feu.esdihumboldt.hale.doc.appschema%2Fhtml%2Fintroduction%2Fintro.html&cp=1_0)